# RestTemplate Uploading File, incorrect Mime-type?

Tags: spring, groovy, mime-types, apache-tika

We're trying to do a file upload as part of a REST call using org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate from the 3.0.5.RELEASE and we're seeing some files, almost all of the Open Office and OOXML formats, show up as our server-side default of application/octet-stream.

We can detect the mime-type using Tika before we upload, but don't see how to add that to part of the request through RestTemplate. Below is some Groovy code that we're using to perform the upload:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>()
form.add("title", document.title)
form.add("description", document.description)
form.add("content", new FileSystemResource(file))
return restTemplate.postForObject(getFullURL(REST_API_URI), form, Document.class)
```